# Ambari file view build failure

Tags: linux, apache, maven, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I am trying to build Apache Ambari file view, I found the source code [here](https://github.com/apache/ambari/tree/release-2.4.0/contrib/views/files), and followed ReadMe, typed mvn clean install to build. The build fails however, and the error message shows as follows:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project files: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.ambari.contrib.views:files:jar:1.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.apache.ambari.contrib.views:ambari-views-commons:jar:2.0.0.0-SNAPSHOT in https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/staging was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of oss.sonatype.org has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
>
> [ERROR]
>
> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> [ERROR]
>
> [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>
> [ERROR] [Help 1] cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException

I checked URL given and cannot find ambari-views-commons.jar, any help is appreciated.

PS. I did not build any other part of Ambari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That project depends on a large number of other ambari projects. You should simply build the entire ambari repo to ensure you have all the dependencies for that specific project. If you navigate to the root of the repo and execute the same `mvn clean install` command it will build the core ambari projects. Then you will need to navigate to the `contrib/views` directory and build that project by running `mvn clean install`, it will build the files project that you want. It appears this contribs area is not well maintained as some of the projects fail to build currently.